# Applet: how to pass parameter from Applet to html

Tags: java, html, applet, parameter-passing

I am aware of how to pass parameter from HTML to Applet, can someone show how to pass parameter from Applet to HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

applet code:

```
public class applet_test extends Applet {
    private InetAddress addr = null;
    public void init() {
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public InetAddress getLHost() {
        return addr;
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<APPLET CODE=applet_test.class Width=0 Height=0></APPLET>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write(document.applets[0].getLHost());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `System.exit(0);` That will not be allowed even for an applet with 'all permissions'.